# Pointer to array of N elements vs pointer to array or to first element of array

Tags: c, pointers, implicit-conversion, return-type, function-declaration

I've got some legacy code in which one function returns pointer to array of 8 uint8_t and the another takes pointer to uint8_t which points to array.

```
typedef uint8_t (*u8_8)[8]; //hope this typedef pointer to array of 8 uint8
```

lets say the implementation of first is as follows

```
u8_8 get(void)
{
  static uint8_t ar[8];
  return &ar;
}
```

the second function takes uint8_t * and do some magic with it

```
void second(uint8_t *data)
{
  //...
}
```

My question is. Are my conversions correct?

```
//...
uint8_t *p = *(get());
second(p);
```

There are no compiler warnings but I just want to make sure.
Thank you and best regards. :)

Comment: The code you have is consistent, and there are no obvious problems from what you've shown.  It is odd that `get` returns `&ar` rather than just `ar`.  The latter would have type `uint8_t *` which seems to be how you're using it, so why take the address, only to immediately dereference it in the caller?

Comment: @TomKarzes I have no knowledge about  implementation of get function, only its header but since compiler does not issue any warning about its return type it must be &ar not ar otherwise I'd get warning about returning incompatible pointer type uint8_t * instead of unsigned char (*)[8]. Just checked it.

Comment: @twar Well, if you return a different pointer you need to adjust the assignment in the caller, too (which seems to be the most obvious thing what you did not do accordingly). That is why you get the incompatible pointer error.

Comment: @twar You misunderstood my comment.  What you have now is consistent.  If you were to change `get` to return `ar`, you would obviously change its declared type, and would remove the dereference from the caller.  That should have gone without saying.  When someone suggests changing the type of the return value, it's implicit that the declaration changes accordingly.  If you have no control over `get`, then this isn't an option, but it's what you would want to do if you wrote it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The function `get` returns a pointer to an array of `8` unsigned bytes.

If you dereference this pointer you get the array it is pointing to.

This array will in turn decay to a pointer (to `uint8_t`, i.e. `uint8_t *`).

Which is exactly what the `second` function is expecting.

In fact you can shorten down the whole thing to a single statement:

```
second(*get());
```

---

With that said, there's really no need for `get` to return a pointer to the array. Instead it could return the array itself, letting it decay to a pointer to its first element:

```
uint8_t *get()
{
    static uint8_t ar[8];
    return ar;
}

...

uint8_t *o = get();
second(p);

// Or: second(get());
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is. Does my conversions are correct?

```
//...
uint8_t *p = *(get());
second(p);
```

You conversion is valid because the expression *(get()) has the type `uint8_t [8]` and used as an initializer it is converted to pointer to the first element of the pointed array.

Returning from the function an object of the type `uint8_t (*u8_8)[8]` instead of an object of the type `uint8_t *` does make sense because you can determine the number of elements of the pointed array. That is in fact the function returns provides two kinds of information: the address of an array and the number of elements in the array.

For example if you have a function that is declared like

```
void func( uint8_t *a, size_t n );
```

then you can easy call it for the returned pointed array from the function get like

```
u8_8 ptr = get();

func( *ptr, sizeof( *ptr ) / sizeof( **ptr ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t (*u8_8)[8];

u8_8 get(void)
{
  static uint8_t ar[8] = "12345678";
  return &ar;
}

void out( const uint8_t *a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        putchar( a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    u8_8 ptr = get();

    out( *ptr, sizeof( *ptr ) / sizeof( **ptr ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

> "*Are my conversions correct? There are no compiler warnings but I just want to make sure.*"

Yes, everything is correct. No syntactic errors and no invoked undefined behavior because all (pointer) types are matching in the respective expressions.

---

```
u8_8 get(void)
{
  static uint8_t ar[8];
  return &ar;
}
```

```
return &ar;
```

`&ar` has type `uint8_t (*)[8]`. Note when you would using `return ar;`, `ar` would decay to a pointer to its first element, type `uint8_t *`; but since the `&` operator is applied to it, it doesn't happen that way. Instead it gains a pointer to the entire array `uint8_t (*)[8]`.

---

```
*(get())
```

The expression `get()` is of type `uint8_t (*)[8]` matching to the type of the returned `&ar` in the called function `get()`.

Dereferencing the pointer to array of 8 `uint8_t` `*(get())` with the `*` operator, type `uint8_t (*)[8]` gains an array of 8 elements of  `uint8_t`, type `uint8_t [8]`. The array decays another time to pointer to the first element of it, type `uint_8t *` which perfectly matches to `p` in the caller, so the assignment is correct.

```
second(p);
```

`second` expects an argument of type `uint8_t *` which is matching to `p` in the caller.

---

Your code could be simplified to:

```
uint8_t* get (void)
{
    static uint8_t ar[8];
    return ar;
}

void second (uint8_t *data)
{
    //...
}

....

int main (void)
{
    uint8_t *p = get();
    second(p);
}
```

Note: The `typedef` of `typedef uint8_t (*u8_8)[8];` is fully unnecessary and redundant now, but you need to change the return type of `get` to `uint8_t *` and also change the initialization of `p` in the caller accordingly.

---

If you don't need the pointer `p` in the caller you even could use the return value of `get()` directly as argument to `second()`:

```
second(get());
```